# holomorphic extension

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ U \subseteq { \mathbb { C } } $ open , $ a \in { U} $ and $ f : U- \left \{ {a } \right \} 
\to { \mathbb { C } } $ holomorphic . Show that if $ f ^ { \prime } $ admits holomorphic extension to all $ U $ then $ f $ admits holomorphic extension to all $ U $ . dm:

As $ a \in { U} $ then open there $ r > 0 $ such that $ B (a, r ) \subseteq { U} $ . Supongamo that $ g : U \to { \mathbb { C } } $ is the holomorphic extension of $ f ^ { \prime } $ then $ g \in { H ( B (a, r ) ) } $ , then as $ B (a, r ) $ is crashed then $ g $ supports primitive . Now is $ f ^ {\prime } (z) = a_0 + a_1z + ... $ and I can integrate as supports primitive relative to a curve B (a, r) which is not closed , then $ f (z) = a_0z + \displaystyle \frac { a_1z ^ 2 } {2} + ... $ with $ f (a) = a_0a $, so we define $ F ( z) = f (z) $ when $ z \in {U - \left \{ {A} \right \}} $ and $ F (z) = a _0a $ when $ z = a $ . I hope you can see if the test is fine , thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

If "$B(a,r)$ is crashed" means "$B(a,r)$ is simply connected", then   your proof seems correct. Indeed, we have $G$, a primitive of $g$, in $B(a,r)$. Since $G'=f'$ in $B(a,r)\setminus \{a\}$, the difference $G-f$ is constant. By subtracting this constant from $G$, we get a holomorphic function in $B(a,r)$ which agrees with $f$ at $z\ne a$. This is what was to be proved.

---

Here is a sketch of another approach, from the weaker hypothesis "$f'$ is bounded". Using integration along line segments, one can show that $f$ is Lipschitz in $B(a,r)\setminus \{a\}$. Therefore it has a continuous extension to $B(a,r)$. Following the proof of Morera's theorem, one concludes that $f$ is holomorphic.